# Terraform plan using terraform cloud back end AWS credential error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Context :

- I have set my aws credentials using aws configure.
- I use terraform remote backend to store the terraform state

Using the following terraform configuration.

```
terraform {
 backend "remote" {
   hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
   organization = "test"

   workspaces {
     prefix = "networking-"
   }
 }
}

provider "aws" {
 region = "eu-west-3"
}
```

Problem:
When I run terraform apply I have this error.

```
    ╷
    │ Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
    │       Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
    │       providing credentials for the AWS Provider
    │ 
    │   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
    │   on main.tf line 13, in provider "aws":
    │   13: provider "aws" {
    │ 
    ╵
```

Comment: Read this section of the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#environment-variables

Comment: Either ensure you have environnment variables set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_DEFAULT_REGION alternatively use credential file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using terraform cloud remote backend by default when you create a workspace, the terraform plan command in executed on the remote backend and not of your local machine. This is why, terraform can not find your credentials, because they are not set in the remote machine. To fix this problem, you need to order terraform to run the plan on your machine. To do so
go in your workspace
[image]
then go in the general settings
[image]
then switch from remote execution mode to local
[image]

Then try to run again your plan on your machine

Comment: So you dont need to port your AWS keys to terraform cloud as environment variables and continue to use terraform locally (plan, apply) with just porting the state management to Terraform cloud

Comment: That was exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks zarathoustra.

Comment: Damn, came here almost after an hour of retries! Thanks

Comment: @omuthu do not forget to upvote :)

Comment: @zarathoustra I did!